# Getting a specific Content Control once loaded Office-js

Tags: office-js

I am currently working on an Office add-in that will check a word doc for content controls, and will take the name and tag of those content controls and make a rest call to SharePoint to check Mod Dates.  I am currently loading the tag and title with out and issue, my question is if I find that the mod dates are not the same, I would like to be able to load that specific Content Control.

**Current Code**

```
function loadContentControls() {
Word.run(function (context) {
    var contentControlProperties = [];
    var contentControls = context.document.contentControls;
    context.load(contentControls, "id");
    return context.sync().then(function () {
        if (contentControls.items.length > 0) {
            for (var x = 0; x < contentControls.items.length; x++) {
                contentControls.items[x].load('title,' + "tag");
            }
        }
        else {
            $("#notificationBody").html("<h4>No Update Found</h4>");
            messageBanner.showBanner();
            messageBanner.toggleExpansion();
        }
        return context.sync().then(function (e) {
            for (var x = 0; x < contentControls.items.length; x++) {
                contentControlProperties.push({
                    Name: contentControls.items[x].title,
                    Moddate: contentControls.items[x].tag,
                });
            }
            return context.sync().then(function () {
                var url;
                var unParsedDateTime;
                var parsedDateTime;
                for (var i = 0; i < contentControlProperties.length; i++) {
                    url = "https://tenant/sites/ContentCenter/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('kist')/items?select=Title,Title&$filter=Title eq '" + contentControlProperties[0].Name + "'";
                    authContext.acquireToken(config.endpoints.SharePoint, function (error, token) {
                        if (error || !token) {
                            console.log('error');
                            return;
                        }
                        else {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: url,
                                headers: {
                                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
                                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                                },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    unParsedDateTime = new Date(data.d.results[0].Modified);
                                    parsedDateTime = unParsedDateTime.toLocaleDateString('en-US').concat(' ' + unParsedDateTime.getHours() + ':' + unParsedDateTime.getMinutes());

                         >> So if there is a date discrepancy I would like to grab that specific content control here  

                                },
                                error: function (error) {
                                    console.log("Fetching list from SharePoint failed.");
                                }
                            })

                        }
                    });
                }
            })
        })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        error.ErrorLocation = "Inserting Content To Doc";
        error.ErrorCode = error.debugInfo.errorLocation;
        error.ErrorMessage = "Could Not Insert Image";
        error.Selection = selectedContents.Name;
        ErrorHandler(error);
    })
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to actually get that specific content control once it was loaded even by id, which I thought would have been possible.  So I went ahead and made a deffered item which I am calling inside the my `context.sync().then()`.  The way this would work is `When my Token get back from adal I will go ahead and execute the for loop`.  This will ensure that my response from SharePoint will be in order, as the code below will show.  So instead of going back and actually loading the specific content control I can keep it all in the ajax call, and when the two time are different I can give that specific content control a red background.

```
 return context.sync().then(function (e) {
            $.when(TokenForSharePoint()).then(function (sharepointToken) {
                if (sharepointToken === "Error") {
                    authContext.login();
                }
                else {
                    for (var x = 0; x < contentControls.items.length; x++) {
                        itemUrl = "https://tenat.com/sites/*site*/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('*list*')/items?select=Title,Title&$filter=Title eq '" + contentControls.items[x].title + "'";
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            async: false,
                            url: itemUrl,
                            headers: {
                                "Authorization": "Bearer " + sharepointToken,
                                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                            },
                            success: function (data) {      
                                var localDocTest = new Date(data.d.results[0].Modified);
                                var spText = new Date(contentControls.items[0].tag);

                                if (localDocTest != spText) {
                                    // I will highlight the content control
                                }                                    
                            },
                            error: function (error) {
                                console.log("Fetching list from SharePoint failed.");
                            }
                        })
                    }                      
                }
```